# Can there be damage to an iPhone 13 Pro Max from using a magnetic cable?

Tags: iphone, hardware, charging, lightning

Can there be any ill effects to an iPhone 13 Pro Max as a result of using a Lightning magnetic cable like this one below to charge it (because of it being magnetic)?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What I have seen about people doing some reviews is that once you have plugged the lightning part in the phone it can be difficult to remove it and could break.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the cable is USB and Lightning standards compliant, there should not be a problem. You haven't included a vendor name, product name, or similar, so it's hard to say something specific about this cable - but it looks like it might be a cheap "China knockoff" and perhaps the vendor does not specify that it is compliant with those standards.

If you're asking in general whether having a small, relatively low-strength magnet located approx 1 cm away from the iPhone's charging port will cause problems - then no, that's very improbable.

There could be any number of other problems with the cable if it is not standards compliants (bad connections, improper shielding, low quality materials, etc) - but the simple fact that it includes a magnet does not itself constitute a major problem.

Comment: You say it looks like a China knockoff; are there "reputable" brands selling cables that do exactly what this one does? The one in the picture is sold under the brand name "Rikbo". Thanks!

Comment: The one in the picture probably goes under many names. You can find it on Alibaba quoted at $0.30 per piece: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/3A-Fast-Charging-Magnetic-Cable-ICAN_1600121498236.html

Comment: The product is similar to products from Baseus (Chinese company) that also feature USB-A/C to Lightning/Micro-USB with a magnetic connection. They're usually sold at prices around 13$ in comparison.

Comment: It's also similar to products from Volta, such as for example this: https://voltacharger.com/products/volta-2-0-3-tips

Comment: The reason why its hard to find these types of cables from more known manufacturers (for example Apple themselves, or for example Logitech or similar) - is probably that it is difficult to produce such a cable that while complying with the USB standards.

Comment: @jksoegaard I would suggest that the reason other manufacturers are not producing these connectors is not the complexity, it's the fact they will have to pay a licence to Apple, for the patented design, but the 'cheap chinese knock off' producers (illegally) don't bother.

Comment: @Neil Perhaps, but it cannot be the reason why Apple themselves do not produce such a cable.